# Create event in google calendar api without login authentication

Tags: javascript, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a customer that wants to do scheduled reservations for his beach house. My thought was to simply set up a Google Calendar and use the API to create and check "reservations" in the form of events. My issue is I cannot find a way to create events to a calendar without a user logging into Google, and even then, it will not add an event to an account other than the account currently logged in. I understand there is the option of a "Google Service Account", but I am trying to find an option that does not incur any extra cost.

Is it possible to develop a REST API to push requests to the desired Google account? That may sound absurd, I have just recently looked into routing a REST API, so I am still unaware of the function and limitations.

Comment: google service account has no extra cost. What makes you think it did? But you have to do it via a server-side language (e.g. PHP, asp.net, nodeJS etc) rather than Javascript, that's all (you can't do it securely enough in a browser, anyone could steal your account key). P.S. You don't need your own REST API, if you don't want, although depending how you want to structure your software you could use that as the interface to your server app, which then communicates with google via the service account. Google's Calendar API is already a REST API acting as the interface to _their_ service.

Comment: Google Calendar can create events from email – you could read up on the format/metadata required, and just send an email to the calendar address instead?

Comment: It has been well over a year since this issue, and I am so sorry to have never responded. Just wanted to say that I appreciate your willingness to help, and I should have been kind enough to at least respond. I took the advice given though and have posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs the help in the future, I ended up using the "google service account" and granting it access to the individual user's calendar. Then all I had to do was send the form data through XMLHttpRequest. I am about to redo the the entire site, so I might update this again, but my approach is going to be about the same except swapping out XMLHttpRequests with fetch requests.